# Add class to element on submit of form when fields are null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form that has several fields all within the class `Contact` that have a common header.

I need that header to turn red whenever the user hits submit with any contact field unfilled. These fields (first_name, last_name, company, Marketing_Phone, email) already have the class `error` added when submitted empty.

These fields are all in the class `wrap_contact` with the label `Contact Information *`. This label **does not** receive the class `error` on submit. This is what I need to add. I gave the label an id of `label2`. So my if then is if first_name, last_name, company, Marketing_phone, or email is null on submit then `label2` has the `error` class added.

I attempted adding the following code, but it did not work.

```
 $( "#pardot-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    var someElements = document.querySelector("p.error,input[name=263882_11763pi_263882_11763]}");

    if (someElements !== "") {
       document.getElementById('p.label2').addClass = 'error';
    }

 };
```

This form is visible online at http://link.rubiconglobal.com/l/263882/2017-03-24/7ssj.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `submit` still occurs and the page is reloaded. You will need to add `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent `submit` action from occurring and reloading the page. Alternatively, since you are using jQuery, you can simply `return false` which does both. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/1736092

Comment: If we do a stopPropogation, how does it allow for the final action once all required fields are full?

Comment: Perhaps I need to clarify. The form submits, and when it does, the error class is automatically added to any fields that don't validate. SO. I need the if statement to be if any contact field has the class error on it, then the label2 class needs to have error added to it.

Comment: You're already doing that, but it's getting undone by the submission. Once there are no errors, your if-statement won't return true and the submission will occur.

Answer (score 0):

If x element has a class then add class to y element:

```
     <script>
     if( $('.first_name, .last_name, .company, .zip, .Marketing_Phone, .email').hasClass('error') === true ) 
    {
    $('p#label2').addClass('label2error');
    }
    </script>
```